# Random fadeOut images sequence is jerky

Tags: jquery

I am running a random image fadeOut sequence which works fine but the actual fade sequence is jerky

```
var speed = 300;
timer= setInterval(function(){
 $notLoaded = $(".cover").not(".loaded");
 $notLoaded.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$notLoaded.length)).fadeOut(500).addClass("loaded");
 if ($notLoaded.length == 0) {
  clearInterval(timer);
 }
}, speed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall `.fadeOut(500)` being *jerky*...
You can always go for CSS3 transitions instead

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/luzipe/1/edit)***

CSS:

```
.loaded{
   transition:0.5s;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```
var speed = 300;
timer = setInterval(function(){
 $notLoaded = $(".cover").not(".loaded");
 $notLoaded.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$notLoaded.length)).addClass("loaded");
 if ($notLoaded.length === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
 }
}, speed);
```

Comment: css3 is the way to go. Much better. Thanks, haven't thought about it

Comment: @rob.m you're welcome. (P.S: Don't forget that old browsers will not applaud to CSS3 transitions)